# Assigning data to individual tabs and using variables to keep track VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'll try to keep it short, and use the actual data/code so you have a better feel for what I'm trying to accomplish.

What I'm trying to do:
Take a large dataset and divide it out to several workers (their daily tasks).
This involves creating the tabs(done), having the manager input the amount of rows to each user (only one time variable inside the macro is what I'm doing now) and then having excel keep track of what number are we on so I don't have to manually hardcode which cells to copy/paste.

Old Version:

```
Sheets("PropFiltered").Select
Range("A1:J1250").Select 'Notice the hard code cell range. I want this to be done automatically.
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("April").Select 'Do not want hard code named sheets. Would like it to grab from Employee1 and so on variables.
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Call WrapText
Sheets("AutoFiltered").Select
Range("A1:J1250").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Christie E.").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Call WrapText
Sheets("AutoFiltered").Select
Range("A1251:J2251").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Cori").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Call WrapText
Sheets("PropFiltered").Select
Range("A1251:J1501").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Cori").Select
Range("A1002").Select 'When a user has both Auto and Property, this has to account for the first "paste" and I would like this to be done automatically.
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Call WrapText
```

New Version (WIP):

```
Sub FillTabs(TabName As String, NumberOfAutoClaims As Integer, NumberOfPropertyClaims As Integer) 'Does it make sense to use a separate sub if I have to keep track of a changing variable (The "what cell should I copy because I've already done the first 1250" variable)

Dim WhatNumberAuto As Integer
Dim WhatNumberProp As Integer
Dim WhatNumberAutoAdjusted As Integer
Dim SettingTheACellAuto As String
Dim SettingTheJCellAuto As String
Dim SettingTheACellProp As String
Dim SettingTheJCellProp As String
Dim SettingThePasteCellAuto As String
Dim SettingThePasteCellProp
Dim Employee1 As String 
Dim Employee2 As String
Dim Employee3 As String
Dim Employee4 As String

Employee1 = "April H.,0,1000" 'I have over 20 employees to add in with 3 variables each, is this the best method? I need to use each variable (separated by comma)
Employee2 = "Christie E.,500,0"
Employee3 = "Cori M.,1000,250"
Employee4 = "Cody S.,1000,250"

Split(Employee1,",") 'This is an example of splitting the employee1 variable to make the three pieces of data useable. Is there a better method?


WhatNumberAuto = 1 'This is to keep track of "What number should I copy now" but is it even possible to have this change if I run this sub separately for each employee?
WhatNumberProp = 1



SettingTheACellAuto = "A" & WhatNumberAuto
SettingTheJCellAuto = "J" & NumberOfAutoClaims
SettingTheACellProp = "A" & WhatNumberProp
SettingTheJCellProp = "J" & NumberOfPropertyClaims
'Sheets(TabName).Select
If NumberOfAutoClaims > 0 Then

    WhatNumberAutoAdjusted = WhatNumberAuto + NumberOfAutoClaims
    'SettingThePasteCellAuto = "A" & (NumberOfAutoClaims + 1)
    Sheets("AutoFiltered").Select
    Range("SettingTheACellAuto:SettingTheJCellAuto").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(TabName).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Call WrapText
Else
    If NumberOfAutoClaims = 0 And NumberOfPropertyClaims = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "This user has no Auto or Property claims assigned"
    End If
    If NumberOfPropertyClaims = 0 Then
        End Sub
    SettingThePasteCellProp = "A" & (NumberOfAutoClaims + 1)
    Sheets("PropFiltered").Select
    Range("SettingTheACellProp:SettingTheJCellProp").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(TabName).Select
    Range(SettingThePasteCellProp).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Call WrapText
End If
```

Newest Version:

```
HowManyTabsDoYouNeed = 21 'If you want to add or remove Tabs, you must change this number AND add/subtract from the "TabName(1)" section below.

ReDim TabName(1 To HowManyTabsDoYouNeed) As String

TabName(1) = "Heather,0,0"
TabName(2) = "Paul,0,0"
TabName(3) = "CICS,0,0"
TabName(4) = "FLPIP,0,0"
TabName(5) = "April H.,0,1000"
TabName(6) = "Christopher H.,0,1000"

......skipping bits of code


'Begin populating employee's sheets.

Dim AutoACount As Integer
Dim PropACount As Integer
Dim AutoAPasteCount As Integer
Dim PropAPasteCount As Integer
Dim AutoJCount As Integer
Dim PropJCount As Integer
Dim AutoRangeA As Range
Dim AutoRangeJ As Range
Dim PropRangeA As Range
Dim PropRangeJ As Range
Dim PropAPasteCountRange As Range

AutoACount = 1
PropACount = 1
AutoJCount = 1
PropJCount = 1
PropAPasteCount = 1

For i = 1 To HowManyTabsDoYouNeed
    SplitTabName = Split(TabName(i), ",")
    If SplitTabName(1) <> "0" Then
        Set AutoRangeA = Range("A" & AutoACount)
        Set AutoRangeJ = Range("J" & SplitTabName(1))
        Sheets("AutoFiltered").Select
        Range(AutoRangeA & ":" & AutoRangeJ).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("SplitTabName(0)").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        AutoACount = AutoACount + SplitTabName(1)
        PropAPasteCount = SplitTabName(1)
    End If
    If SplitTabName(2) <> "0" Then
        Set PropRangeA = Range("A" & PropACount)
        'MsgBox PropRangeA
        Set PropRangeJ = Range("J" & SplitTabName(2))
        Set PropAPasteCountRange = Range("A" & PropAPasteCount)
       ' With Sheets("PropFiltered").Range("PropRangeA:PropRangeJ")
       '     .Copy
        Sheets("PropFiltered").Select
        Range(PropRangeA & ":" & PropRangeJ).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("SplitTabName(0)").Select
        Range(PropAPasteCountRange).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        PropACount = PropACount + SplitTabName(2)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Is there a question anywhere?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm really winging this, so I doubt what I have done is the correct method. Can you tell me the best method of taking one variable "Employee1" above with multiple parameters and having excel do tasks based on those multiple parameters. While doing that task, it needs to keep track of "Okay, I gave April 1250 rows, so I should start Cori on row 1251" and so on. Is it possible to pass back and forth a "I've ran this function no times so I should do this" and "I've ran this function 1 time so I should do this" or should I put this all in one Sub?

Comment: I've edited the code to include my questions on each piece. Thanks to anyone that takes the time to answer.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: I attempted to implement an array then using the split function get the variables I need. Now I can not set a range using these split functions (and some math) without getting errors. Can you take a look at this updated code?